# How to filter Power Query by date I have pulled in from Excel?

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

So I have pulled the below date in Excel whose table name is BacklogDate into Power Query to use as a filter with the below code.
[image]

```
 let
     Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="BacklogDate"]}[Content],
     #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Backlog Date", type date}}),
     SourceBackLogDate = Record.Field(#"Changed Type"{0},"Backlog Date")
 in
     SourceBackLogDate
```

Then I'm trying to use it as a filter in the below code but the format is different in the below filter and I can't figure out how to get it to filter by the BackLogDate.

```
  #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Extracted Date", each [DataCollectionDate] = #date(2019, 8, 24) or [DataCollectionDate] = #date(2019, 7, 27))
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Code that worked

```
 let
     BackLogDate = BackLogDate,
     Source = Sql.Database("JANSQL02", "Data Warehouse"),
     dbo_SFDCOpportunitiesByDay_JAN = 
 Source{[Schema="dbo",Item="SFDCOpportunitiesByDay_JAN"]}[Data],
     #"Extracted Date" = 
 Table.TransformColumns(dbo_SFDCOpportunitiesByDay_JAN, 
{{"DataCollectionDate", DateTime.Date, type date}}),
     #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Extracted Date", each 
 [DataCollectionDate] = BackLogDate)
 in
     #"Filtered Rows"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of filtering by a date query named MyDateFilter.  Just change the date code for the name of the date query.

```
FilterByDateQuery = Table.SelectRows(AddCol_CreatedDate, each [Created Date] = MyDateFilter)
```

Comment: So I have put my updated code that worked in my edited question. Just have to figure out a formula to get prior months date pulled in and filtered off of it as well but I should be able to handle that. Thanks!